# Get random username

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely new to MySQL and PHP and I'm trying to  further develop the [AndroidIM](https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM) project.
This is the php server code which it's based on:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

require_once("mysql.class.php");

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbName = "name";


$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

// if operation is failed by unknown reason
define("FAILED", 0);

define("SUCCESSFUL", 1);
// when  signing up, if username is already taken, return this error
define("SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED", 2);  
// when add new friend request, if friend is not found, return this error 
define("ADD_NEW_USERNAME_NOT_FOUND", 2);
// TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS: if last authentication time of user is older 
// than NOW - TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS, then user is considered offline
define("TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS", 60);
define("USER_APPROVED", 1);
define("USER_UNAPPROVED", 0);
$username = (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && count($_REQUEST['username']) > 0) 
                            ? $_REQUEST['username'] 
                            : NULL;
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
$port = isset($_REQUEST['port']) ? $_REQUEST['port'] : NULL;
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
if ($action == "testWebAPI")
{
    if ($db->testconnection()){
    echo SUCCESSFUL;
    exit;
    }else{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
    }
}

if ($username == NULL || $password == NULL)  
{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
}

$out = NULL;

error_log($action."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
switch($action) 
{

    
    case "authenticateUser":
    
        
        
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {                   
            
            // providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
            // providerId is the Id of making first friend request
            // requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId
            
            // fetching friends, 
            // left join expression is a bit different, 
            //      it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself
            
            $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                        f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                            from friends f
                            left join users u on 
                                        u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                            where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                         f.requestId = ".$userId." ";
                                         
            //$sqlmessage = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
            
            $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username from messages m \n"
    . "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
            
    
            if ($result = $db->query($sql))         
            {
                    $out .= "<data>"; 
                    $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
                    while ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                    {
                        $status = "offline";
                        if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                        {
                            $status = "unApproved";
                        }
                        else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                        {
                            $status = "online";
                             
                        }
                        $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";
                                                
                                                // to increase security, we need to change userKey periodically and pay more attention
                                                // receiving message and sending message 
                        
                    }
                        if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                            {
                            while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                                {
                                $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                                $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                                $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                                }
                            }
                    $out .= "</data>";
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
                // exit application if not authenticated user
                $out = FAILED;
        }
        
    
    
    break;
    
    case "signUpUser":
        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
             $email = $_REQUEST['email'];       
                
             $sql = "select Id from  users 
                            where username = '".$username."' limit 1";
             
        
                            
             if ($result = $db->query($sql))
             {
                    if ($db->numRows($result) == 0) 
                    {
                            $sql = "insert into users(username, password, email)
                                values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ";                          
                                            
                                error_log("$sql", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql))   
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out = SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED;
                    }
             }                      
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
    
    case "sendMessage":
    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {   
        if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
        {
             $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
             $message = $_REQUEST['message'];   
                
             $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";
             
             
        
                    if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                    {
                        while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                        {
                            $uto = $rowto->Id;
                        }
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";                       
                                            
                                error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                       
                        $resultto = NULL;
                    }   
                                    
        $sqlto = NULL;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
    
    case "addNewFriend":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {
            
            if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
            {               
                 $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];
                 
                 $sql = "select Id from users 
                                 where username='".$friendUserName."' 
                                 limit 1";
                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                             $requestId = $row->Id;
                             
                             if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {
                                     $sql = "insert into friends(providerId, requestId, status)
                                         values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".USER_UNAPPROVED.")";
                             
                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;  // user add itself as a friend
                            }                                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }                               
                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }
            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
    
    case "responseOfFriendReqs":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {
            $sqlApprove = NULL;
            $sqlDiscard = NULL;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['approvedFriends']))
            {
                  $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['approvedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }
                        
                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";
                        
                    }               
                    
                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlApprove = "update friends set status = ".USER_APPROVED."
                                    where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                ";      
                  }
                                  
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['discardedFriends']))
            {
                    $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['discardedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }
                        
                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";
                        
                    }                   
                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlDiscard = "delete from friends 
                                        where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                    providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                            ";
                  }                     
            }
            if (  ($sqlApprove != NULL ? $db->query($sqlApprove) : true) &&
                        ($sqlDiscard != NULL ? $db->query($sqlDiscard) : true) 
               )
            {
                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }
    break;
    
    default:
        $out = FAILED;      
        break;  
}

echo $out;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)
{
    
    $sql22 = "select * from users 
                    where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' 
                    limit 1";
    
    $out = NULL;
    if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
    {
        if ($row22 = $db->fetchObject($result22))
        {
                $out = $row22->Id;
                
                $sql22 = "update users set authenticationTime = NOW(), 
                                                                 IP = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' ,
                                                                 port = 15145 
                                where Id = ".$row22->Id."
                                limit 1";
                
                $db->query($sql22);             
                                
                                
        }       
    }
    
    return $out;
}

?>
```

Now I want to select a random user from my database.
I know how to do the app part, but as I already said I have no idea how to do the server part.
Could somebody please tell me how to this?

Comment: There are multiple ways to use "random". In PHP, or in SQL. PHP would be `mt_rand()` or `uniqid()` or some others am sure, and SQL is simply `RAND()` in your case `ORDER BY RAND()` --- You get the basic gist of it.

Comment: I also noticed you are using MD5 for password storage. I suggest you don't use that. It's old and considered too "fast". Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: It's true what is asked itself is confusing because of the line `Now I want to add a function to give the app a random username`. I think you should also learn how to well format a English sentence well.

Comment: @Rahul Let's go easy on the "English sentence" thing. ;-) The OP's native language may not be English or be as good as yours and mine. ;-)

Comment: @Rahul: _also learn how to well format a English sentence well_ - People who live in glass houses...

Comment: @TheBlueDog People who live in glass houses stone live in throwing.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, sole point of the comment is `make your point clear and loud`. so that people can give a correct answer. Not to heart someone's ego/sentiment.

Comment: @Rahul: Just a tip: backtick formatting is only for inline code, not highlighting specific parts of your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

This query will randomly select an `username` from `users` table.

**EDIT:**

If your table contains thousands of records, `RAND()` would not be a good idea. So another alternative is:

1. Find the largest id of username using `MAX(userid)`.
2. Pick a random number which is less than the largest id from php.
3. Query of the record with the random number. Like:

   ```
   SELECT username
   FROM users
   WHERE userid='$randnum'
   ```

This method will be faster since it is querying against a constant value.

Comment: So this: `case "randomUser":
  if (isset($_REQUEST['random']))
  {
    $random = $_REQUEST['random']; 
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users
     ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 1";
   if ($result = $db->query($sql))   
   {
   $out .= "<data>"; 
   $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
   while ($rowrandom = $db->fetchObject($result))
     {
     $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'/>";
     }
   $out .= "</data>";   
   }  
 }` Would work fine?

Comment: @user3557747: Why not just test it?

Comment: @user3557747 That... that isn't how comments are to be used. Like, **at all**.

Comment: Just a note: `ORDER BY RAND()` is known to be slow. Read [this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

Comment: Maybe save `RAND()` and use it with `LIMIT` and offset then it should be good without `ORDER BY`. Resulting float should be converted to `COUNT` range.

Comment: Something like `SET rand=ROUND(RAND()*rowcount);` should work here for conversion.

Answer (score -1):

This would give you a random 5 digit string. You can modify the length by changing the last digit (5) in this scenario.

```
$RandNumber = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 5);
```

Comment: Sidenote: `mt_rand()` is faster than `rand()`

Comment: But I don't need a completely random string , I need a username which already exists in the table.

Comment: You should say that then. You wrote 'Now I want to add a function to give the app a random username. '. Not I want to select a random user from my database. In that case you need @Raging Bull's answer.

Comment: @MattTheNinja Just so you know, I did `not` downvote this.

Comment: But @Fred-ii- it's *three more characters* to type. That's time you'll never get back by choosing to use `mt_rand()` over `rand()` for "performance" reasons.

Comment: @salathe It was a "sidenote", that is all ;-) just pointing a technical fact.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're going to be pointing out facts, at least qualify them.  `mt_rand()` is *marginally* faster than `rand()`, we're talking about fractions of nanoseconds per call on modern hardware. That's like saying I blink faster than you blink (who cares?!).